# QtCreator breakpoint not reached in QML

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, qml

I configurated my QtCreator project, to show a GUI written with QML and all the algorithmic part on a C++ class connected to my GUI (classic thing in Qt so far). What I want is to be able to debug the QML and the CPP to debug easier later in my project. For the example, I take the code from the [The second tutorial of Qt for QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-tutorial2.html). I also followed the instruction of the [Qt page which exaplins how to debug QML and CPP](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-qml.html) to configure my project.

My environment is:

- Linux Red Hat 7
- Qt Creator 4.8.2
- Qt 5.12.2
- GCC 4.8.5
- Cmake 3.13.2
- Make from GNU 4.1
- Account without right to install anything :( but if really necessary I can ask for some installation software

The compilation is done without error. When I start the debugger, I have the following message:

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

***----- EDIT1: not anymore this warning updating the sysroot parameter of the kit -----***

So, all seem to be okay for the debugger. But a first weird thing happens at the start of the debugger, before to reach first breakpoint in the main.cpp without other warning or error, I have two messages like this which are pop between "Continue" action in the debugger:

[image: Warning when starting debugger]

With the following messages in the Linux terminal:

> SOFT ASSERT: "state() == EngineRunRequested || state() == InferiorStopOk" in file /home/qt/work/build/qt-creator/src/plugins/debugger/gdb/gdbengine.cpp, line 4612
> "InferiorRunRequested"

For me, it is just warning, because I can reach the first breakpoint of my main.cpp. But I prefer to give this information in case of it is something very wrong.

***----- END EDIT1 -----***

Another information is when I stop the debugger, I have the following message:

[image: Error message stopping the debugger]

For information, I have the following configuration of my project (you will see I have the case "Qml debugging and profiling" as mentioned in my link above):

[image: Debug settings]
[image: Run settings]

And for my kit:

[image: Kit configuration]

Any help you can bring me will be appreciate because I am a novice in Linux and also to configure a project for the debugger. Until now, all was worked on first time but I change of project and PC. So thank you in advance !

Comment: Your Qt version is rather old.

Comment: I do with tools I gave me :D Thank you for your usefull comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded to make it works. How? Adding these two magic lines in the *CMakelists.txt* file:

- `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DQT_QML_DEBUG ")` : to set the debug flag for the compiler about QML
- `TARGET_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)` :

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that the first error is caused by the code you are debugging? Does the code run correctly when not in debugging mode?

Also, are you running the code in Debug mode?
Finally, it looks a bit strange that she Sysroot parameter in your kit configuration points to a folder in the Trash...

Comment: Ok I didn't see this parameter (sysroot) so thank you. I make it empty and now, I have not anymore the warning at the start. In run mode (wuthout debugging), it is working normally. For me I am in Debug mode (with F5 key) and still not breakpoint reached in QML part.

Comment: Unfortunately debugging problems with Qt creator are quite common. Is there a chance you can upgrade Qt creator to a newer version and try again?

Comment: I'll see if I can't update it. It is only about Qt Creator ? Not the debugger ?

Comment: I personally had problems with Qt Creator way more often than with debuggers, but you can for sure try downloading a different version of the debugger and see if the problem persists. Maybe before doing that you can go do the debugger folder and try executing `gdb`, see if it executes correctly or it gives errors.

Comment: Look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#enabling-the-infrastructure), the documentation states you should pass the QT_QML_DEBUG define to your compiler. Are you doing that? Maybe there is some useful indication in the rest of the page too

Comment: Ok I will see with the IT team what I can do. For the QT_QML_DEBUG flag, yes I already use it ;) Thank you